# Weird artifacts with sans serif fonts in math mode

Tags: math-mode, fonts, math-fonts

I have followed this
https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/385068/80468
advice to enable me to change the font with `\sffamily` in math mode:

```
\DeclareMathVersion{sfmath}
\SetSymbolFont{letters}{sfmath}{OT1}{\sfdefault}{m}{n}
\xapptocmd{\sffamily}{\mathversion{sfmath}}{}{}
```

However, this gives some weird artifacts, particularly with the use of lowercase Greek characters and periods. In fact, periods are converted to colons, so that

`{\sffamily $a_1 \ldots a_n$}` actually prints as if I was typing `{\sffamily $a_1 ::: a_n$}`.

What is the best way to overcome this?

**Edit (minimal working example)**

```
\documentclass[american, hidelinks]{report}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

\usepackage{xpatch}

% Math fonts.
\DeclareMathVersion{sfmath}
\SetSymbolFont{letters}{sfmath}{OT1}{\sfdefault}{m}{n}

\xapptocmd{\sffamily}{\mathversion{sfmath}}{}{}

\begin{document}

{\sffamily
\[
  a_1 \ldots a_n = \mathit{foo}
\]
}

\end{document}
```

gives

[image]

Comment: Now I can reproduce the problem. I will remove my "answer".

Comment: The default encoding for `letters` is OML, mapping them in full to OT1 doesn't work.

Comment: It is unrelated to sans serif, you have changed the `letters` family from `OML` to `OT1` which means you need to redefine almost every math command to the new layout, most likely you have removed lower case greek altogether (as OT1 does not have lower case greek)

Comment: The [answer you linked to](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/385068/69818) is flawed in the first place: ***very*** strange, considering who authored it.

Comment: @GuM The answer is not flawed in any way. The OP is simply taking it for what it isn't supposed to do.

Comment: There is plenty of topics about sans serif math.