# Latex dot symbol in verbatim mode

Tags: biblatex, verbatim, math-operators, code

so I have a problem, I need to put in a dot symbol between my equations in verbatim mode.
For some reason it does not work in verbatim mode, but I surely need my equations in verbatim.
So do you guys know how to solve it?

here is are the screenshots

[image]
[image]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Insert symbols inside verbatim mode LaTeX](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/150965/insert-symbols-inside-verbatim-mode-latex)

Comment: Do you *need* `verbatim`? I don't think so.

Answer (score 1):

You don't really need `verbatim`, but you can use it.

```latex
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}

\begin{flushleft}\ttfamily
\%\%Sinusse \\
y1 = x1·sin(w·t); \\
y2 = x2·sin(3w·t); \\
y3 = x3·sin(5w·t); \\
y4 = x4·sin(7w·t); \\
y5 = x5·sin(9w·t); \\
y6 = x6·sin(11w·t); \\
\end{flushleft}

\begin{verbatim}
%%Sinusse
y1 = x1·sin(w·t);
y2 = x2·sin(3w·t);
y3 = x3·sin(5w·t);
y4 = x4·sin(7w·t);
y5 = x5·sin(9w·t);
y6 = x6·sin(11w·t);
\end{verbatim}

\end{document}
```

[image]

With an older version of LaTeX (pre 2019), you want to add `\usepackage{textcomp}`.

Comment: grazzie!!
Where did get the dots for this?
Becasue iour answer helped a lot ,but where can I find those dots?

Comment: @TechSupportNotFromSchool Any Unicode viewer shows it. The particular one is U+00B7 MIDDLE DOT

Comment: ah buono, grazzie!